# How to Save contents of a textbox to a file

Tags: c#

I have looked around on several answers to similar questions, but somehow this isnt working for me.
I am trying to save the contents of a textbox into a user promptet file.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream;
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, rtbIncoming.Text);
            myStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The User prompt pops up as expected, and the file is generated but without any content.

Comment: Well you kind of open the file twice. Just remove the inner if (and the `myStream`) completely and it should work.

Comment: Why are you using SaveFileDialog.OpenFile method? This is blocking writing text to the file.

Comment: I realize that now, and it is works by changing it to the answer below.

Comment: dont't you get a `System.IO.IOException` exception thrown? It should tell you that another process is accessing the file

Comment: no i did not, everything worked as expected except the file was empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to open the file stream yourself. `File.WriteAllText()` does all this for you. So this should be enough:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, rtbIncoming.Text);
```

I guess your code leads to an empty file *because* you open a seperate stream that isn't used to write and closed (and flushed) *after* the call to `WriteAllText()`.